# How can we show that the set is countable?

Tags: analysis

I am trying to show that the set $F$ of functions $f: \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$ where $f(n)=0$ except for finitely many elements $n \in \mathbb{n}$ is countable.  I understand that the set $A$ of all functions $f:\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$ is uncountable, as this is just the set of all sequences whose elements are the digits 1 and 0.  In trying to prove this current problem, though, I've let $F_x$ to be the set of functions in $F$ such that $F_x(n)=1$ for $x$ elements of $\mathbb{N}$.  If I can show that all $F_n$ are countable, then I can show $F$ is countable as $F$ is the countable union of these countable sets.  I am trying to show this by induction, but the inductive step is eluding me. Any thoughts?

Comment: $\mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$, not $\{0,1\} \to \mathbb N$.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the correction!

Comment: Set F is basically sequences which is zero except for finitely number of elements, therefore try to express F as countable union of countable sets

Comment: There is an obvious 1-1 correspondence of $f$ to the binary numbers.  And binary are a representation of $\mathbb N$

Answer (score 1):

The set $F$ of functions can be put in bijective correspondence with (finite) words made up from the alphabet $\{0,1\}$. So for example, the word '01001' is the function $f$ defined by

$\quad f(0) = 0, \,f(1) = 1, \,f(2) = 0, \,f(3) = 0, \,f(4) = 1 \text{ and } f(n) = 0 \text{ for } n \gt 4$

We call these words F-Strings; except for the F-String '0', they all end with a '1'.

If we can put these F-Strings in bijective correspondence with $\mathbb N$, we will know that $F$ is countable.

The following Python program shows that this is possible, where the natural number $n \ge 0$ gets mapped to the ${(n+1)}^\text{th}$ output string of the program.

```
#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*
# Desc: Define a bijection of the natural numbers to the functions in F
#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*

import sys

#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------#
while True:#                       M A I N L I N E                             #
#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------#
#                                  # initialize state of function machine
    growing_01_word_list = ['0', '1']
    print('0', '', end='')
    print('1', '', end='')
    token_len = 0

    while True:
        g01wl_segment_LEN = len(growing_01_word_list)
        token_len = token_len + 1
        for i in range(0, g01wl_segment_LEN):
            token = growing_01_word_list[i]
            tok1 = token.ljust(token_len, '0') + '1'
            growing_01_word_list.append(tok1)
            print(tok1, '', end='')
        if token_len == 7:
            print('...', end='')
            print("\nProgram stopping after printing all F-Stings with length less than or equal to ", token_len + 1)
            sys.exit()
```

OUTPUT:

```
0 1 01 11 001 101 011 111 0001 1001 0101 1101 0011 1011 0111 1111 00001 10001 01001 11001 00101 10101 01101 11101 00011 10011 01011 11011 00111 10111 01111 11111 000001 100001 010001 110001 001001 101001 011001 111001 000101 100101 010101 110101 001101 101101 011101 111101 000011 100011 010011 110011 001011 101011 011011 111011 000111 100111 010111 110111 001111 101111 011111 111111 0000001 1000001 0100001 1100001 0010001 1010001 0110001 1110001 0001001 1001001 0101001 1101001 0011001 1011001 0111001 1111001 0000101 1000101 0100101 1100101 0010101 1010101 0110101 1110101 0001101 1001101 0101101 1101101 0011101 1011101 0111101 1111101 0000011 1000011 0100011 1100011 0010011 1010011 0110011 1110011 0001011 1001011 0101011 1101011 0011011 1011011 0111011 1111011 0000111 1000111 0100111 1100111 0010111 1010111 0110111 1110111 0001111 1001111 0101111 1101111 0011111 1011111 0111111 1111111 00000001 10000001 01000001 11000001 00100001 10100001 01100001 11100001 00010001 10010001 01010001 11010001 00110001 10110001 01110001 11110001 00001001 10001001 01001001 11001001 00101001 10101001 01101001 11101001 00011001 10011001 01011001 11011001 00111001 10111001 01111001 11111001 00000101 10000101 01000101 11000101 00100101 10100101 01100101 11100101 00010101 10010101 01010101 11010101 00110101 10110101 01110101 11110101 00001101 10001101 01001101 11001101 00101101 10101101 01101101 11101101 00011101 10011101 01011101 11011101 00111101 10111101 01111101 11111101 00000011 10000011 01000011 11000011 00100011 10100011 01100011 11100011 00010011 10010011 01010011 11010011 00110011 10110011 01110011 11110011 00001011 10001011 01001011 11001011 00101011 10101011 01101011 11101011 00011011 10011011 01011011 11011011 00111011 10111011 01111011 11111011 00000111 10000111 01000111 11000111 00100111 10100111 01100111 11100111 00010111 10010111 01010111 11010111 00110111 10110111 01110111 11110111 00001111 10001111 01001111 11001111 00101111 10101111 01101111 11101111 00011111 10011111 01011111 11011111 00111111 10111111 01111111 11111111 ...
```

Program stopping after printing all F-Stings with length less than or equal to  8

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if there are only finitely many $n$ for which $f(n) = 1$, there is some $M$ such that these are all $\le M$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The number of functions $f: \{1,2,3,\dots,n\} \to \{1,2\}$ is equal to $2^n$, and is therefore finite and countable.

See Robert Israel Hint.

---

Your idea of expressing the set as a countable union of countable sets works, but the problem is to define subsets that make your life easier - you don't need induction.

Hint: Express the set $F$ as a countable union of finite sets.